# The plyr:: mapvalues() function

Tags: r, dplyr

Is there a more updated version of the plyr:: mapvalues() function (in the tidyverse) or is it still the best general way to change individual values in a variable e.g. changing an integer in a categorical Gender variable from 0 to male and 1 to female?

Comment: `recode()` or `case_when()` ?

Comment: Got it to work with `recode()` thanks! Feel like `plyr::mapvalues()` is more intuitive but `recode()` is a simpler verb to remember.

Comment: Cool! please accept my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dplyr::recode()` and `dplyr::case_when` can do that.

Comment: Honestly, dplyr versions are not as good as `mapvalues()`. `mapvalues()` works with replacement with `NA`. One can use `case_when()` for this too but it's more verbose.